# Como excluir informações confidenciais do histórico de edição da postagem?

Tags: suporte, exclusão, histórico-de-revisões

Infelizmente publiquei uma resposta e acabei postando informações de conexão de um banco de dados pessoal. Editei a resposta, mas as informações ficaram no histórico de edição da resposta. Já alterei as informações por questão de segurança, mas gostaria de remover aquele histórico para evitar de ter informações de acesso disponíveis na rede.

Como proceder?
Obs.: A resposta até o momento contém votos, mas não foi aceita.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sinalize a publicação explicando que postou dados sensíveis e que devem ser removidos, os funcionários da empresa e moderadores vão analisar a demanda, e se necessário utilizar ferramentas específicas para remover esse tipo de conteúdo.

Comment: Já realizei a sinalização. Agora como eu acompanho?

Comment: Fica de olho no histórico de edição, @Djalma. Você também pode acompanhar o status da sinalização em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/48384 (só você tem acesso a essa lista)

Comment: @DjalmaManfrin tá feito, dá uma conferida lá como ficou

Comment: @Math vlw. Tudo certinho.