# É possível excluir algo permanentemente do site?

Tags: suporte

Quando removemos algo que é de nossa autoria desta comunidade, percebemos que o conteúdo permanece lá, com uma tarja indicando:

> **Esse post está escondido.** Você deletou esse post X mins atrás.

Existe uma forma de excluir esse conteúdo **permanentemente** do site? Sem esconder, ou de forma que permaneça em relatórios ou para usuários com altas reputações no site?

E se não existir, por que o nosso conteúdo nunca é excluído da plataforma?

Comment: O usuário aceita uma licença ao postar, deixando o conteúdo pra comunidade. Além disso, tudo é passível de auditoria. Veja este post: **[Eu sou dono do meu conteúdo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6038/70)** - Obviamente que em casos extremos, pode haver remoção total, mas mediante intervenção (são exceções à regra). Aí é o caso de sinalizar a postagem, embasar a justificativa, e será analisado. **[Como excluir informações confidenciais do histórico de edição da postagem?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6198/70)**.

Comment: Complementando: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/401803 | https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121586/401803